# Transforming a Haskell JSON Lens expression back to JSON

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, haskell-lens

How can I suffix the following Aeson Lens expression

```
>>> "{\"a\": 4, \"b\": 7}" & members . _Number *~ 10
"{\"a\":40,\"b\":70}"
```

so that the result is a `Value` (with an `Object` constructor) and not a `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `_Value` prism to convert to `Maybe Value`, then proceed from there. The flipped `fmap` operator `<&>` from the lens library provides nice syntax for cases like this:

```
"{\"a\": 4, \"b\": 7}"^? _Value <&> members . _Number *~ 10
-- Just (Object fromList [("a",Number 40.0),("b",Number 70.0)])
```

Comment: Nice I think I would prefer the _Value prism

Answer (score 2):

You can use `decode` from [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:2) to parse your string and then use lenses as before:

```
ghci> (decode "{\"a\": 4, \"b\": 7}" :: Maybe Value ) & _Just . members . _Number *~ 10
Just (Object fromList [("a",Number 40.0),("b",Number 70.0)])
```